# How to set a taxonomy term programmatically for a node?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I created taxonomy terms and assigned it to a content type '**Article**' using term reference field. I created nodes by programmatically but how to set taxonomy terms for the nodes?

The taxonomy terms are created already. I want to set the taxonomy term for a node **programmatically**.

Answer (score 18):

Use this function to get ID from Termname

```
function _get_tid_from_term_name($term_name) {
  $vocabulary = 'tags';
  $arr_terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name, $vocabulary);
  if (!empty($arr_terms)) {
    $arr_terms = array_values($arr_terms);
    $tid = $arr_terms[0]->tid;
  }
   else {
    $vobj = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($vocabulary);
    $term = new stdClass();
    $term->name = $term_name;
    $term->vid = $vobj->vid;
    taxonomy_term_save($term);
    $tid = $term->tid;
  }
  return $tid;
}
```

Comment: I like its versatility (the else part of it), so it adds the term.

Answer (score 16):

When you creating a node programmatically, you can assign it to any term like this:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_NAME';
$node->title = 'title';

$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
node_object_prepare($node);

//id of your taxonomy term
$tid = 1;

//add term to a node field
//field_yourfield_name - machine name of your term reference field

$node->field_yourfield_name[$node->language][0]['tid'] = $tid;
node_save($node);
```

Comment: @neok.Thanks.It works well using term id.But to how to set termnames? is that like  $node->field_yourfield_name[$node->language][0]['name'] = $termname;

Comment: Anyone know how to tag node(programatically) using taxonomy termname instead of taxonomy id in drupal 7?

Comment: @pretty Use taxonomy_get_term_by_name to get the term object and then use the tid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some [entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) to achieve that, e.g.:

```
try {
  $w_node = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
  $w_some_term = entity_metadata_wrapper('taxonomy_term', 1234);
  $w_node->field_term_ref = $w_some_term->tid->value();
  $w_node->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Error for node: @title, message: @error.',
        array('@title' => $w_node->title->value(), '@error' => $e->getMessage())), 'error');
  watchdog_exception('foo', $e);
}
```

Comment: +1 for using EMWs. They also have a handy method getIdentifier(), which is one less step than `$w_some_term->tid->value()`. Here's a [great article](http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/entity-metadata-wrapper) that helped me understand this concept so much better, and to which I refer regularly when using EMWs:

Answer (score 1):

When adding terms, I found I needed to add $term->parent = array(0) otherwise the taxonomy_term_hierarchy table isn't updated properly, and the terms don't show in the admin list page for that vocabulary