# How can I set the value of a taxonomy term reference to multiple terms using PHP?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

[This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76319/how-to-set-a-taxonomy-term-programatically-for-a-node) describes how to set the value of a term reference field using PHP.  But what do I do if I want to set the value of a term reference field in the user profile to multiple terms?

I am trying to set the value to term IDs 27 and 28.  Here is my code so far:

```
$user->field_yourfield_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] = 27;
user_save($user);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the field is set up to accept multiple records...

```
$user->field_yourfield_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] = 27;
$user->field_yourfield_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][1]['tid'] = 28;
// etc
```

Or you can just keep appending to the array (without knowing the next available index) like this:

```
$user->field_yourfield_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['tid'] = 27;
$user->field_yourfield_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['tid'] = 28;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to a list value that contains [entity metadata wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers). For example:

```
<?php
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
  foreach ($wrapper->field_taxonomy_terms->getIterator() as $delta => $term_wrapper) {
    // $term_wrapper may now be accessed as a taxonomy term wrapper.
    $label = $term_wrapper->name->value();
    $tid = $term_wrapper->tid->value();
    // you can also set the values
    $term_wrapper->name = 'New label';
    $term_wrapper->tid = array(123, 1234); // or ...
    $term_wrapper->tid->set($tids_to_set);
  }
  $wrapper->save();
?>
```